# Identify the position of duplicate characters in a row using R

Tags: r, dplyr, character

Let's say that my data is the following:

```
Date                                Price
01.01.2017 00:00 - 01.01.2017 01:00 20.96
01.01.2017 01:00 - 01.01.2017 02:00 20.90
01.01.2017 02:00 - 01.01.2017 03:00 18.13
01.01.2017 03:00 - 01.01.2017 04:00 16.03
01.01.2017 04:00 - 01.01.2017 05:00 16.43
01.01.2017 05:00 - 01.01.2017 06:00 13.75
01.01.2017 06:00 - 01.01.2017 07:00 11.10
01.01.2017 07:00 - 01.01.2017 08:00 15.47
01.01.2017 08:00 - 01.01.2017 09:00 16.88
01.01.2017 09:00 - 01.01.2017 10:00 21.81
01.01.2017 10:00 - 01.01.2017 11:00 26.24    #duplicate
01.01.2017 10:00 - 01.01.2017 11:00 26.38    #duplicate
01.01.2017 11:00 - 01.01.2017 12:00 26.42
01.01.2017 12:00 - 01.01.2017 13:00 27.66
01.01.2017 13:00 - 01.01.2017 14:00 28.70
01.01.2017 14:00 - 01.01.2017 15:00 29.66
```

I want to use the column Date which is formed by characters for finding where is the duplicate observation? As you can see I can not define a path and use `str_detect` because the days and hours always are changing.

Comment: Your example data has no duplicates?

Comment: yes, it does. Lines 11 and 12

Comment: Ohh..right. So what is your expected output? Both line 11 and 12 or do you want to remove them?

Comment: My original base has more than 1 million observations, so I would know the number of the row of lines. In this case, the position is c(11, 1) and c(12, 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` in both the directions to get row numbers which are duplicates.

```
inds <- which(duplicated(df$Date) | duplicated(df$Date, fromLast = TRUE))
inds
#[1] 11 12
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("01.01.2017 00:00 - 01.01.2017 01:00", 
"01.01.2017 01:00 - 01.01.2017 02:00", "01.01.2017 02:00 - 01.01.2017 03:00", 
"01.01.2017 03:00 - 01.01.2017 04:00", "01.01.2017 04:00 - 01.01.2017 05:00", 
"01.01.2017 05:00 - 01.01.2017 06:00", "01.01.2017 06:00 - 01.01.2017 07:00", 
"01.01.2017 07:00 - 01.01.2017 08:00", "01.01.2017 08:00 - 01.01.2017 09:00", 
"01.01.2017 09:00 - 01.01.2017 10:00", "01.01.2017 10:00 - 01.01.2017 11:00", 
"01.01.2017 10:00 - 01.01.2017 11:00", "01.01.2017 11:00 - 01.01.2017 12:00", 
"01.01.2017 12:00 - 01.01.2017 13:00", "01.01.2017 13:00 - 01.01.2017 14:00", 
"01.01.2017 14:00 - 01.01.2017 15:00"), Price = c(20.96, 20.9, 
18.13, 16.03, 16.43, 13.75, 11.1, 15.47, 16.88, 21.81, 26.24, 
26.38, 26.42, 27.66,28.7, 29.66)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know at what timeslot the `Price` column is duplicated. Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, you may try:

```
df$Date[duplicated(df$Price)]
```

Comment: it helps a lot, but I still have a doubt. My original base has more than 1 million observations, so I would know the number of the row in the column `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

- Putting your data into a tibble and adding an index number for the rows:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tribble(
~Date,                               ~Price,
"01.01.2017 00:00 - 01.01.2017 01:00", 20.96,
"01.01.2017 01:00 - 01.01.2017 02:00", 20.90,
"01.01.2017 02:00 - 01.01.2017 03:00", 18.13,
"01.01.2017 03:00 - 01.01.2017 04:00", 16.03,
"01.01.2017 04:00 - 01.01.2017 05:00", 16.43,
"01.01.2017 05:00 - 01.01.2017 06:00", 13.75,
"01.01.2017 06:00 - 01.01.2017 07:00", 11.10,
"01.01.2017 07:00 - 01.01.2017 08:00", 15.47,
"01.01.2017 08:00 - 01.01.2017 09:00", 16.88,
"01.01.2017 09:00 - 01.01.2017 10:00", 21.81,
"01.01.2017 10:00 - 01.01.2017 11:00", 26.24,   
"01.01.2017 10:00 - 01.01.2017 11:00", 26.38,  
"01.01.2017 11:00 - 01.01.2017 12:00", 26.42,
"01.01.2017 12:00 - 01.01.2017 13:00", 27.66,
"01.01.2017 13:00 - 01.01.2017 14:00", 28.70,
"01.01.2017 14:00 - 01.01.2017 15:00", 29.66
) %>% 
  mutate(index = row_number())
```

- Finding the row number, and any other columns

```
df[which(duplicated(df$Date) | duplicated(df$Date,fromLast = T)),c("index","Price")]

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  index Price
  <int> <dbl>
1    11  26.2
2    12  26.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   add_count(Date) %>% 
   summarise(ind = which(n  > 1)) %>% 
   pull(ind)
#[1] 11 12
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("01.01.2017 00:00 - 01.01.2017 01:00", 
"01.01.2017 01:00 - 01.01.2017 02:00", "01.01.2017 02:00 - 01.01.2017 03:00", 
"01.01.2017 03:00 - 01.01.2017 04:00", "01.01.2017 04:00 - 01.01.2017 05:00", 
"01.01.2017 05:00 - 01.01.2017 06:00", "01.01.2017 06:00 - 01.01.2017 07:00", 
"01.01.2017 07:00 - 01.01.2017 08:00", "01.01.2017 08:00 - 01.01.2017 09:00", 
"01.01.2017 09:00 - 01.01.2017 10:00", "01.01.2017 10:00 - 01.01.2017 11:00", 
"01.01.2017 10:00 - 01.01.2017 11:00", "01.01.2017 11:00 - 01.01.2017 12:00", 
"01.01.2017 12:00 - 01.01.2017 13:00", "01.01.2017 13:00 - 01.01.2017 14:00", 
"01.01.2017 14:00 - 01.01.2017 15:00"), Price = c(20.96, 20.9, 
18.13, 16.03, 16.43, 13.75, 11.1, 15.47, 16.88, 21.81, 26.24, 
26.38, 26.42, 27.66,28.7, 29.66)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```